# Sentence structure: Both + 2 adjectives + noun

Tags: adjectives, nouns, singular-vs-plural, conjunction-reduction

1. Both American and Canadian culture are...
2. Both American and Canadian cultures are...

Which sentence is correct?

Comment: The second one. The first is ungrammatical.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\[Singular\] Is/Are \[Plural\]?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/17766/singular-is-are-plural)

Comment: But _both American and Canadian culture is..._ is also grammatical, with the meaning that you are treating them as a single culture.

Comment: @ColinFine I don't think that it is usually used in that way, though. If you wanted to refer to American and Canadian cultures as one, you would probably say North American culture.

Comment: I agree. It would only be used if you were specificlly (but incidentally) arguing that American and Canadian culture were a single thing (for some purpose). But take a different example, and _both red and white wines are ..._ and _both red and white wine is ..._ are both grammatical, with a slightly different meaning.

Comment: Thanks, guys! I`m going to go with the second one, since I want to treat them separately.

Comment: The first one's fine. It's conjunction reduction of _American culture is ... and Canadian culture is ..._, and since it winds up being more than one it's plural and takes _are_. Just like _Both Miami and New York are in the East._

Answer (score 1):

This looks to me like an example of [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics)), where a repeated section of a sentence is omitted. In this case, with that text pencilled back in, it would look like this:

> Both American *culture* and Canadian culture are...

Written like this, it is clear that **culture** should be singular, and the verb should be plural.

Answer (score 0):

The verb would have to agree with "Both", so it would be "Both____ are..." However, you can change it to "American and Canadian culture is..."

Comment: Hi Gwen. I think the question was more *culture* vs. *cultures*.